# Can HTTPS requests be made via proxy server?

Tags: .net, ssl, https, httpwebrequest

```
Dim Request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://www.mysite.com/mysecurepage.php")
Request.Method = "POST"
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Request.Proxy = New WebProxy("http://myproxy.com:8080");
Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream())
    writer.Write(params)
End Using
```

If an `HttpWebRequest` is made via a proxy server where the proxy server is addressed with `HTTP` and not `HTTPS` (as above), is it possible to achieve an `SSL` connection with the destination `HTTPS` URL?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to make a SSL connection through a HTTP proxy.

Comment: @feroze: even if the proxy server address begins with `HTTP` and not `HTTPS`?

Comment: yes. You can do HTTPS through an HTTP proxy.